# How to make synchronous file_get_contents() GET request in PHP

Tags: php, file-get-contents, synchronous

On my site, I needed a way to share session data between two domains (one using a shared SSL certificate, and the other one over plain http) so as to redirect a user from the secure domain to the normal one after logging in, all while preserving the session data.

So this is what I came up with:

1. The user enters his credentials in the secure login page and submits the form.
2. When the form is submitted, the page refreshes. Upon refresh, the user is authenticated, a session is started and the session variables get set. Then, the SID of the user on the secure domain gets sent as GET data to a page on the non-secure domain, where the secure SID is set as a session variable.
3. The user gets redirected to the main non-secure page, the session is started, the secure SID is read, and finally, the session on the non-secure domain is restarted with the secure SID. This way, the same session is preserved across domains.

There is only one problem with this approach, the file_get_contents() I make gets canceled as soon as the code reaches the redirect header. In code:

```
    //The following line never completes
    file_get_contents('http://nonsecuresite.com/cookie.php?sid=session_id()');
    header('Location: http://nonsecuresite.com');
```

Of course the SID is encrypted, but I omitted that for the sake of clarity.

Is there any way to make the script wait for the request to complete before moving on to the next page, a synchronous file_get_contents function?

Comment: You are sure it is canceled? Php should be synchronous, as you CAN do $var = file_get... And then use $var in the redirect. That wouldn't be possible if it was async. You are most likely or, forgetting to get the session_id function outside the ' or you can't use file_get_contents for url (recommend), instead use curl.

Comment: Pretty sure, since the session change completes if I comment out the redirect and open the non-secure page in a new tab.

Comment: Well, as you are calling the page FROM Php, the session variables should be given to Php too, so I don't see how this van work in the first place (it should not) (but the function does complete, Php barely had async functions (there is only a async curl version somewhere) and many things would break if file_get_contents was)